# Launch MS Access from Winforms

Tags: winforms, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out how to launch a specific page/form in an Access project from a winforms app. Basically I'm trying to link the two applications via hyperlink or button or whatever (clicking on a button from a winforms form should take the user to that specific form in the access project). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can launch MSAccess using [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

and

Open a Page/Form in MSAccess using [Command-Line switches in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207)

to achieve your task you need to [Create Macros in MSAccess](http://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/tutorial/create_a_macro.cfm) to Open the specified page/form depend on your needs. you can call the Macro by specifying some parameters. here you need to use `/Excl` to open the database exclusively and `/X` to run the Macro.

a sample workaround is here

```
Process access = new Process();
access.StartInfo.FileName = "msaccess.exe";
access.StartInfo.Arguments = @"e:\test.mdb /Excl /X Macro1"; 
access.Start();
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this did help. I'm stuck though: when I specify the macro to run, nothing happens. Here's my code: 'code'    Process access = new Process();
                    access.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\vm_dev\\ER_SQL.adp";
                    access.StartInfo.Arguments = "/X OpenTicket";
                    access.Start();

Comment: you need to mention FileName as "msaccess.exe" and StartInfo.Agruments as @"C:\vm_dev\ER_SQL.adp /Excl /X OpenTicket" and then specify access.Start